# Авторизация с помощью RSA publicKey

Tags: c#, c++, rsa, auth

В общем, пишу программу на C++ для работы со Steam. Застрял на авторизации, при которой пароль шифруется при помощи принятых  с сервера modulus и exponent значений через RSA и дальше в виде Base64 отправляется обратно на сервер.

Одни ребята практически сделали всё за меня, но нормально реализовать тоже самое на C++ не сумел (перерыл достаточное количество библиотек, нет подходящих функций, чтобы принимали указанные значения).

[Видео тех ребят с ответом на C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LKrVTv93h8)

Код из видео:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Rsacs
{
   public class Rsacs
    {
        private byte[] _exponent;
        private byte[] _modulus;

        public string Exponent
        {
            set
            {
                _exponent = hexToBytes(value);
            }
        }

        public string Modulus
        {
            set
            {
                _modulus = hexToBytes(value);
            }
        }

        public string Encrypt(string data)
        {
            string encrypted;
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            var parameters = new RSAParameters();
            var provider   = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            parameters.Exponent = _exponent;
            parameters.Modulus = _modulus;

            provider.ImportParametrs(parameters);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(provider.Encrypt(byteData, false)).ToString();

        }

        private byte[] hexToBytes(string hex)
        {
            byte[] arr = new byte[hex.Length >> 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length >> 1; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = (byte)((getHexVal(hex[i << 1]) << 4) + (getHexVal(hex[(i << 1) + 1])));
            }
        }

        private int getHexVal(char hex)
        {
            int val = (int)hex;
            return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 55);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Основная часть кода, на самом деле, заключена в этих строчках:

    var parameters = new RSAParameters();
    var provider   = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

    parameters.Exponent = _exponent;
    parameters.Modulus = _modulus;

    provider.ImportParametrs(parameters);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(provider.Encrypt(byteData, false)).ToString();

которые представляют собой отсылки к конкретным сервисам, т.е. просто взять и переписать по шаблону вряд ли получится, пока у аналогов в с++ не идентичный интерфейс.

Answer (score -1):

Решено: буду использовать CLI (весь этот код теперь заставил работать, правда используя специальные конвертеры. Придётся переучиваться). 
Вопрос возникал не только у меня, так что держите: 
<del>http://pastebin.com/B1bvNWYd</del>

---

Обновление
К сожалению, с тех пор всего кода не осталось.
Привожу тот фрагмент, что использовал приведённый в начале код, который был скомпилирован в библиотеку.
Я тогда долго мучался и забил, но, как я помню, позже выяснилось, что для работы нужно было вставить кавычки к строке.

rsa.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h> 

typedef void (WINAPI * LPFN_set_Exponent) (const char *);
typedef void (WINAPI * LPFN_set_Modulus) (const char *);
typedef char* (WINAPI * LPFN_Encrypt) (const char *);

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hMyDLL = LoadLibrary("NewDllRsaCS.dll");
    if (NULL == hMyDLL)
    {
        std::cout << "LoadLibrary failed\n";
        return -1;
    }

    LPFN_set_Exponent SetExponent = (LPFN_set_Exponent)GetProcAddress(hMyDLL, "set_Exponent");
    if (NULL == SetExponent)
    {
        std::cout << "GetProcAddress set_Exponent failed\n";
        return -2;
    }


    LPFN_set_Modulus SetModulus = (LPFN_set_Modulus)GetProcAddress(hMyDLL, "set_Modulus");
    if (NULL == SetModulus)
    {
        std::cout << "GetProcAddress set_Modulus failed\n";
        return -3;
    }

    LPFN_Encrypt Encrypt = (LPFN_Encrypt)GetProcAddress(hMyDLL, "Encrypt");
    if (NULL == Encrypt)
    {
        std::cout << "GetProcAddress Encrypt failed\n";
        return -4;
    }


    SetExponent("000001");
    SetModulus(std::string('o', 112).c_str());  // 
    char * str = Encrypt("password");
    std::cout << str;

    FreeLibrary(hMyDLL);

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

rsa.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#using <mscorlib.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Security::Cryptography;

namespace Rsacs
{
   public ref class Rsacs
   {
    private:
        array<Byte> ^_exponent;
        array<Byte> ^_modulus;

    public:
        property String ^Exponent
        {
            void set(String ^value);
        }

        property String ^Modulus
        {
            void set(String ^value);
        }

        String ^Encrypt(String ^data);

    private:
        array<Byte> ^hexToBytes(String ^hex);

        int getHexVal(Char hex);

        std::string SysToStd(System::String^);
   };
}
```

Не знаю кому и зачем это ещё может быть нужно (в виду огромного кол-ва готовых решений первоначальной задачи - работы с api стима), но пожалуйста, больше ничем помочь не могу.

Comment: Ссылка не работает (вот примерно поэтому ссылки на Stack Overflow не одобряются)

Comment: @andreymal обновил. А вообще смотрите на дату сперва)

Comment: Дата никак не отменяет неработоспособности ссылки)